# Castle.Microkernel - could no load file or assembly

Tags: castle-windsor

I was using Castle project libraries in the one of the projects, but now other projects does not work because it is now required to use this library. When I start project it shows exception:
Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.MicroKernel' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

web.config, machine.config, references - no Castle.MicroKernel reference. Also I tried to change IIS application pool - it did not help too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying

1. I have two projects, A and B. Project A references project B.
2. I have added Castle to project B.
3. I have copied the new project B into my project A deployment and it's stopped working, needing Castle.

If that's correct then you'll have to copy the Castle assemblies into project A's bin directory now. Project B depends on them so you'll need to include Castle wherever you're using project B.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windsor 2.5, the Castle.MicroKernel.dll has been merged and doesn't exist anymore. You have to recompile all your dependencies against the new Windsor dll.